# How to save a kitten that has its stomach getting bigger and bigger due to feces?

Tags: diseases, defecation, feces

We took the kitten to the vet, the vet said it had lots of feces in the stomach and unable to excrete properly due to the curvature of the spine.

It was given laxatives and pain killers, but after a day and discharged from the vet, the stomach is even much bigger than when we brought the kitten to the vet. The stomach is large for a kitten.

Maybe the laxative and painkillers are not the solution but time is short if it doesn't get resolved the kitten will probably pass away in a few days. The vet did not allow people in the office and only through the guard so we have no idea what its chances are.

The kitten was never able to walk properly. It always limped and struggled and would always end up on its back for the whole day. Lately, the cat never walked anymore and just kept peeing itself so we had to bring the kitten to the vet.

Answer (score 4):

If the kitten has deformities that causes problems for its ability to defecate it is very little one can do.

You need to talk with the vet and ask what is best for the kitten,there are times in life where letting go is the only responsible thing to do.

Please take a look at the situation do you have the resources to give the kitten a good life or is this impossible as a result of the kittens deformities.

When i say resources it means money and time to get possibly multiple surgeries done on your kitten and the time to suport the kittens for several weeks after the surgery is done.

The pain of letting go is the price we pay for loving somebody.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Sadly the kitten just died a few moments ago its tummy was enormous the laxative given by the vet didn't help